# How to represent a JSON file in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm quite a beginner and trying to get the OpenWeather API JSON to show up in my challenge project.

I managed to model it

```
struct WeatherRespose: Codable {
    var weather: [Weather]
    var name: String
}
```

&

```
import Foundation


struct Weather: Hashable, Codable {
    var main: String
    var description: String
}
```

In addition to fetch the data in ContentView. However, when I try to present it:

`@State var weatherForcast = Weather()` or `@State var weatherForcast = WeatherResponse()` I get this error: Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call, insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'

The only thing that worked for me is to present the data in an array:

`@State var weatherForcast = [Weather]()`

Any idea what am I missing? thank you so much! Ran

Comment: When you say `@State var weatherForcast = Weather()`, what do you expect the initial values of `main` and `description` to be? You never specified anything.

Comment: Why @State, are you going to edit the weather data? Other than that the last code snippet looks like the best solution to me but then again it’s not clear what you want to present in your view.

Comment: Depending on what you want, `Weather` or `WeatherResponse`, 
when you declare `weatherForcast` you need to use something like `@State var weatherForcast = Weather(main: "", description: "")` or `@State var weatherForcast = WeatherResponse(weather: [], name: "")`. Your will not have any error. When you use `@State var weatherForcast = [Weather]()`, you declare it as an empty array of `Weather`, and that works.

Answer (score 1):

I made pretty simple example of how you can do this. There are several additional files, so it's easier to understand how it works in details:

1. Create additional file called `NetworkService`, it will fetch weather data:

```
import Foundation

final class NetworkService{

    private let url = "https://example.com"
    
    func performWeatherRequest(completion: @escaping (Result<WeatherResponse, Error>) -> Void){
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    completion(.failure(WeatherError.failedToDownload))
                    return
                }
                                
                let weatherResponse: WeatherResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: data)
            
                completion(.success(weatherResponse))
                
            }.resume()
    }
    public enum WeatherError: Error {
            case failedToDownload
    }
}
```

2. Create simple ViewModel which will retrieve data from our `NetworkService` and prepare to present it in `ContentView`

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

extension ContentView {
    @MainActor class ContentViewVM: ObservableObject {
        private var networkService = NetworkService()
        
        @Published var currentWeatherMain: String?
        @Published var currentWeatherDescription: String?
        
        func fetchWeather(){
            networkService.performWeatherRequest { [weak self] result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let weatherResponse):
                        self?.currentWeatherMain = weatherResponse.weather[0].main
                        self?.currentWeatherDescription = weatherResponse.weather[0].description
                    case .failure(_):
                        print("oops, error occurred")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Add our `ContentViewVM` to our `ContentView`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ContentViewVM()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("The main is: \(viewModel.currentWeatherMain ?? "")")
            Text("The description is: \(viewModel.currentWeatherDescription ?? "")")
        }
        
        .onAppear{
            viewModel.fetchWeather()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.